# List Initializer assignment to 2d array EXC_BAD_ACCESS error

Tags: c++

```
class Matrix {

    double** contents;
    uint r;
    uint c;

public:

    Matrix(const i_list & list);            // constructor (using initializer list)
    Matrix::Matrix(uint rows, uint cols){
    r = rows;
    c = cols;
    contents = new double * [r];
    for (int i = 0; i < r; ++i){
        contents[i] = new double[c];
        for (int j = 0; j < c; ++j){
            contents[i][j] = 0.0;
        }
    }
};


 Matrix::Matrix(const initializer_list<initializer_list<double> > & list){

    r = list.size();
    c = (*list.begin()).size();

    for (int i = 0; i < r; ++r){
        for (int j = 0; j < c; ++c){
            contents[i][j] = *((list.begin() + i)->begin() + j); // EXC_BAD_ACCESS error
         }
    }
};
```

I want to assign an initializer list into a dynamically allocated array like this:

Matrix d = {{1, 2},{3, 4}};
I get an EXC_BAD ACCESS error and the program stalls. Does anyone know what might cause this?

Comment: Yes, there is a better way -- `typedef std::vector<std::vector<double>> Matrix;  Matrix d = {{1,2}, {3,4}};`

Comment: What are the disadvantages of using initializer lists like in the code?

Comment: There are no disadvantages if what you want to do is initialize (not assign, but initialize).  My point is that you could do all of that code you've written in just 2 lines of C++.

Comment: Please post real code. `i_list` and `uint` are not declared. Also the form `Matrix::Matrix(` cannot appear inside the class definition.

Comment: In the initializer_list constructor you write `contents[i]` but contents` is an uninitialized pointer

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
Matrix d{{1, 2}, {3, 4}};
```

In your initializer list constructor, `c` should be determined within the `i` loop, since the different lists may have different sizes.

Edit:

After the question was edited with the runtime error, that constructor hasn't initialized `contents` so it will crash.